# Signalr: getting hubcontext with unity di

Tags: unity-container, signalr

I started using unity to inject stuff into one of my hubs. This works, but, when I resolve a hubcontext somewhere outside my hub it seems like i'm getting the wrong one. This is because when I try to send messages with it, connected clients don't get them.

Dependencyresolver:

```
public class SignalRUnityDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver, IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IUnityContainer _container;
        public SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }
        public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (_container.IsRegistered(serviceType)) return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
            else return base.GetService(serviceType);
        }
        public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (_container.IsRegistered(serviceType)) return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            else return base.GetServices(serviceType);
        }
    }
```

What I register in my container:

```
container.RegisterType<MessageHub>(new InjectionConstructor(new EFAuthRepository()));
```

My hub:

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    IAuthRepository _repository;
    public MessageHub(IAuthRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

How I resolve outside my hub:

```
 var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();
```

Is there anything else that needs to be registred?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the instance of the **resolver** to get the IConnectionMananger from the container as explained [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/extensibility/dependency-injection). 
Althought it is for Ninject you can get the idea. (look at at the bottom). This ConnectionManager can get you the HubContext as you were used to via *GlobalHost*.

```
resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<MessageHub>()
```

We made a simple example to ilustrate this (Ninject and Unity examples using signalr) and you can check it out [here](https://github.com/genuinefafa/signalr-di-examples). If you are eager for the setup, it is [here](https://github.com/genuinefafa/signalr-di-examples/blob/master/WithUnity/App_Start/HubConfig.cs#L47). ;)

Let me know if it helps.